# How to update details to existing spl-token

Tags: metadata, solana, metaplex

I am trying to update the token metadata for my existing token. Is there any other steps needed to be carried out to update the token metadata correctly?

I have updated the token metadata by using **Strata Protocol Token Launchpad** (https://app.strataprotocol.com/edit-metadata) 1 week before. But it didn't reflect on the token logo and name at all on the Solana Explorer.

**Token Address:** https://explorer.solana.com/address/7KG5WNqNbUdXY5MBX7TUVZMTSD5cGoYxwYwry96GD1sM/metadata

1. How can I update token name and logo correctly?
2. How can I edit or remove the social channels link with metadata?

Any help is appreciated as always. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The new standard to SPL token metadata is actually that the same of NFT's now.

Each token will have it's own token metadata account (which will need creating if token was created via the SPL Token CLI), in your case once was created for you if you used Strata to create the token.

Updating the SPL token metadata is now as simple as updating an NFT on Solana. Various tools such as https://metaboss.rs is one, Strata website should also work to update the token tool. I've also got a site which after testing updates tokens too just fine but at the moment adds in some unessaccery data related to NFT's, but functions. If you wish to try that let me know in a comment.

If Strata doesn't work for you you could try [Metaboss](https://metaboss.rs).
You'll need to first upload an image and a JSON file to arweave that you would then link to each other.

1. Upload Image to Arweave or similar.
2. Create and upload a new json file (to arweave or similar) with a few attributes inside it.

https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list

You can see from the above document at Solana Labs that you need

```
 {
  "name": "TOKEN_NAME",
  "symbol": "TOKEN_SYMBOL",
  "description": "TOKEN_DESC",
  "image": "TOKEN_IMAGE_URL"
}
```

in your JSON file. Your image URI should be a link to the image you uploaded in step one.

3. You can then use the update commands at metaboss to upload some onChain details such as name, symbol, and the URI.
   https://metaboss.rs/update.html

Comment: Looks like a needed git repository is not there anymore:
Clone the source: git clone git@github.com:samuelvanderwaal/metaboss.git

Has anyone figured out how to update the SPL Token metadata?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm got same problem here,

In my case, I `setAuthority` of the SPL token to `null` right after initiate and mint to make sure no one could ever mint more.

What they said "**You must have mint authority in order to create or update the metadata**", mean that existing spl-token have no way to update their metadata.